# Python - Custom icon for display dialogue statement in AppleScript

Tags: python, user-interface, popup, applescript

How do I use a custom icon (in this case a png file) for the display dialog statement in AppleScript called using subprocess in a Python script? [There's docs that elude to a solution here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayDialogsandAlerts.html), but don't seem to applicable in my Python script.

I've worked out I can change the icon to `caution`, `stop`, or `note` but have been unable to workout how to use a custom icon. I tried replacing `caution` with a directory to the file but does not seem to work. Any ideas? Is it even possible using my method?

```
import subprocess

applescript = """
display dialog "Some message goes here..." ¬
with title "This is a pop-up window" ¬
with icon caution ¬
buttons {"OK"}
"""

subprocess.call("osascript -e '{}'".format(applescript), shell=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. You need to use `with icon file` and write the directory using colons `:`.

```
import subprocess

applescript = """
display dialog "Some message goes here..." ¬
with title "This is a pop-up window" ¬
with icon file "Users:UserName:path:to:file:icon.png" ¬
buttons {"OK"}
"""

subprocess.call("osascript -e '{}'".format(applescript), shell=True)
```